# How to get list of topics in azure service

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to get list of topics in service bus in .NET CORE App.

There is a way to get topics list using old service bus nuget package(WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) .

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
NamespaceManager nm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
IEnumerable<TopicDescription> topicList=nm.GetTopics();
        foreach(var td in topicList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(td.Path);
        }
```

But we can't use this package [(WindowsAzure.ServiceBus)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) in .NET Core applications.

.NET Core compatible package is [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) and I did not find any help on the documentation page.

Comment: Since you mention that you're in the process of migrating packages, you may wish to consider that [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) is the current generation package.   `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` is the previous generation and while it will continue to be supported for some time, it is moving to a maintenance mode and will be receiving bug fixes but is unlikely to see new features and enhancements.   Microsoft recommends using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` for new development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For listing topics (or queues), you will need to use [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management?view=azure-dotnet) namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;

namespace SO68789585
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://namespacename.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sharedaccesskey";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var managementClient = new ManagementClient(ConnectionString);
            var topics = await managementClient.GetTopicsAsync();
            foreach (var topic in topics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(topic.Path);//Prints topic name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For interested readers, the equivalent in the current generation package, `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` is the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` in the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration` namespace.